# Hugo Icarus Theme and Blogdown unable to disable sidebar

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm using Hugo Icarus theme. n order to use the full width of the website I disabled the profile on the left and and the widgets on the right for a single page in the frontmatter following [read_me file](https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-icarus-theme#sidebars):

```
+++
disable_profile = true
disable_widgets = true
+++
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is a `toml` header but you use a `yaml` header. Thus this needs to be something like:

```
--- 
title: Hello R Markdown 
author: Frida Gomam
date: '2015-07-24' 
categories: 
  - R 
tags: 
  - plot 
disable_profile: true 
disable_widgets: true
---
```

Comment: Thanks finally I solved it, but leave this question for anyone who has the same issue. Thanks a lot!